# undefined state flashbuilder 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, state, flex4.5

I'm currently having some problems when switching to flex 4.5. In some components, I declared 2 states (opened, closed). At app creation, I set all the components to "closed" state. When launching the ap with flex 4.1, there are no problems. But now that I updated the version to 4.5, I got an error saying : "closed" state is undefined at runtime. Does someone heard about some kind of issues ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you setting all the components to closed state even if not all of them have the closed state?  Why not just set it to default as being closed and have it self manage their states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for the help but I solved the problem. It was linked to the **graphite theme** I applied to my app. I replaced it by the default spark theme. Themes may not be up to date  with the new 4.5 version of the builder. Anyway, I took your component state self managment into account :).

Answer (score 0):

You can set "currentState" directly in the component's tag.

***Example Component:***

```
<s:Group    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
            currentState="closed">

    <s:states> 
        <s:State name="closed"/>
        <s:State name="open"/>
    </s:states>

</s:Group>
```

Comment: Note: Having the `closed` state listed first makes that the default and renders unnecessary `currentState="closed"`